# How to add extra content to a Jenkins job default view page in Jenkins plugin development

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I want to develop my own Jenkins plugin, and my request to display some extra information (Show the build status in another related job) on the right side of view page in a pipeline job as shown in the red box in the snapshot.
Any one knows how to make it possible?
[image]

I read some document and find out that there is a jelly file action.jelly which allows users to add extra links on the side panel. But I didn't find any similar jelly file for the main panel.